# How to Find the Cube Vector coord (X, Y, Z) of an Index number?

Tags: c#, vector, mathematical-optimization, game-development

I can convert a Coordinate into an Index like so:

```
index = z + y * maxZ + x * maxY * maxZ
```

So for instance, I have a cube of 4x8x4... But my brain, isn't connecting how to convert it back.
I want to take a given 'Index' and get 'x', 'y' and 'z'.  That is in a 'quick' smart way.  I know I could do it with loops and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `index = z + y * maxZ + x * maxY * maxZ`, you get `(x, y, z) = (index / maxY / maxZ, (index / maxZ) % maxY, index % maxZ)`.

Comment: Ok, you were helpful, but I had to turn around your answers this way:
x = squareIndex % maxZ; int y = (squareIndex / maxZ) % maxY); int z = squareIndex / maxY / maxZ; //note truncation takes place here, but its ok. Int-part